Get path without arguments
In my api.php file, I might have a path that says Route::post('/this/thing/{variable}'
In another part of my codebase, when a request is made to that route, I can get the actual requested route with $request->path();, but if I do that, {variable} is of course replaced by whatever the request route actually put in there.
I want a $request->path() alternative that gives me the string '/this/thing/{variable}' without replacing {variable}, is that possible?

I believe you are looking for request()->route()->uri()

Yes, you can get the route definition (including the placeholder like {variable}) using the following:
$route = $request->route()->uri();

This will give you the route URI with the placeholders ({variable}), instead of the actual value passed in the request.
Route::post('/this/thing/{variable}', function (Request $request) {
  $routeDefinition = $request->route()->uri(); 
  return $routeDefinition; // returns '/this/thing/{variable}'
});

This will return the original route string with {variable} as part of it, which is what you are looking for.
